# What would the best way be to share an attribute amongst a mesh island using geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

So the base of these joysticks (the sticks on the arcade machines, there are two per arcade machine and these anre individual of each other) each have an average position vector which is constant per joystick. I need this position to be shared amongst every point in the joystick, not just the base as it is now, so say the vector on the base of the joystick is (1,1,1), then the rest of the joystick where it is currently (0,0,0) would need to be set to (1,1,1). All other values are 0. I would share the node setup, however since this is for nodevember it is needlessly large and complicated, so I think the abstract might be more useful. Any advice at all would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.